# Unexpected question mark in Windows/bash

Tags: bash, git, mingw

I'm trying to automatically "archive" some local branches on Windows using the MinGW Bash on Windows.

I copy and pasted the content of `git branch` on a txt file (`branches_to_be_archived.txt`) and then I wrote:

A script to archive a single branch

```
#!/bin/bash
BRANCH_NAME=$1
echo "Branch name is $BRANCH_NAME"
git tag archive/$BRANCH_NAME $BRANCH_NAME
git branch -D $BRANCH_NAME
```

A script to archive every branch from a file

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=./branches_to_be_archived.txt
LINES=$(cat $FILE)
for LINE in $LINES
do
    ./archive_branch.sh.txt $LINE
done
```

I inserted some echo prints and they are ok but executing git commands will raise an error like this:

```
fatal: Failed to resolve '[actual name of the branch]?' as a valid ref.
```

With a trailing ? that is not shown anywhere.

Any way to avoid having this question mark at the end?

Comment: Could be a line ending character.

Comment: Try to convert your script file to Linux-style newlines and see if the problem disappears. However, trying to reproduce your error on my machine, I see that my current version of Git Bash finally accepts CRLF as line ending. I'm glad that's the finally case, but maybe you're running an older version. I remember it used to be a problem all the time, having to be careful to make all bash script use linux-style newlines.

Comment: For the record, my Git Bash is using `GNU bash, version 4.4.23(2)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)`. Let us know what `bash --version` outputs for you, in case it's relevant.

Comment: From the comments to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/577663/handling-bash-script-with-crlf-carriage-return-in-linux-as-in-msys2 it looks like Git Bash (well, Bash on MSYS, really) started supporting CRLF line endings with version 4.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, it was a endline characters issue (Win `CRLF` and Linux `LF`).

I solved by using `Notepad++` and setting `EOL -> Linux (LF)` but I think that `dos2unix` for branches list file works just fine